# 乱数の list をなるべく短いコードで生成したい

Tags: c#, unity3d, random

Unity c#で乱数で初期化されたlistを使いたいのですが今の方法だと以下のように長いコードになってしまいます。
Pythonになれた私にとっては毎回このように書かないといけないのは非常に面倒です。

もっときれいに、できれば一行で乱数のlistを作成する方法はありますか？

```
List<int> outputs = new List<int>();
foreach (int z_ in Enumerable.Range(0, output))
{
    outputs.Add(Random.Range(0, wall_len));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(0,output).Select(_=> Random.Range(0, wall_len)).ToList();
```